# From "Reinstate Monica" to "Save Ukraine"

Tags: discussion, display-names

I’ve noticed that profile names are more and more used to display slogans or to make some form of propaganda. It all probably started with the “Monicagate” when a number of users across all SE sites added slogans to support Monica in their profile names. Recently, the Russia-Ukraine war is producing the same effect on some profile names.

Is it correct to add slogans or phrases with personal or political content in profile names? Do we risk that profile name become a battlefield for political issues? (Pro Ukraine or pro Russia for instance). Does all that comply with SE rules?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Etiquette for username changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259825/etiquette-for-username-changes)

Comment: @Nij . Not really

Comment: @Nij . It does not address the “political” aspect I ask about.

Comment: Very clearly, people can make their username anything they like, as long as it adheres to the code of conduct. "Do we risk that usernames become a battlefield" - what... They have been for years, nearly as long as Stack Exchange existed, why be suddenly concerned now, just because people are supporting Ukraine with it?

Comment: @Nij - the problem is not supporting Ucraine (which I do) but what if  a user name saying “ destroy Ucraine”?

Comment: @Gio it's U**k**raine, with the letter "k", not "c".

Comment: Anyway, display name "Destroy Ukraine" or "Kill all Ukraine people" (can replace Ukraine with any other country name) is already against the ToS and/or CoC, and should be reported,

Comment: I support Ukraine in their fight to defend their country from invaders. It's the first time I've ever modified my username in 9 years. If someone tells me to keep my political opinions to myself I will consider that request as being anti-free speech.

Comment: @Mari-LouAСлаваУкраїні . The issue here is not Ukraine but the use of usernames for political reasons. Is or there should a limit to that?

Comment: If the username is not violent, racist, sexist, vulgar or uses offensive language, I don't see a problem.

Comment: @Mari-LouAСлаваУкраїні / I do see a lot of problems….political and social issues are not that clear-cut. But what  I don’t understand is what usernames have got to do with all this.

Comment: Again, if the username is non-violent but supports a person  or country under attack it should be allowed. There will always be someone looking to stir trouble and incite a reaction but any aggressive or provoctive comments posted can be flagged. And you know this.

Comment: Ok, I see there is no interest on this issue here.

Comment: @Gio 81 views, 18 votes, how is this "no interest"? That's just normal and even above, for a 5 hours old question.

Comment: @ShadowWizardSaysNoMoreWar - user probably just downvote on the “duplicate” notion. I edited the question, but….

Comment: No, users here usually don't vote based on something being duplicate. They vote because they agree or disagree with what's written in the post. That is how Meta works. And voting means they show interest, even if not agreeing.

Comment: @ShadowWizardSaysNoMoreWar - still I don’t get an answer. Why does SE support (encourage) political/social slogans even in the space of usernames. I thought SE was arranged into different  subjects (law, languages, maths etc.) what has politics to do with all this?

Comment: @Gio encourage means someone goes and ask people to do something. SE does not do that; No SE employee ever asked users to change their name. They also don't support it. They simply don't prevent it, that's it. I understand the need to blame SE for things, I also don't like SE for various reasons, but that's just not one of them.

Comment: @Mari-LouAСлаваУкраїні Most (well, all, in the extent you elaborated on them) of those conditions you provided re: "as long as it's not X" are also protected by 'free speech'. It is important to keep in mind that Stack Exchange users do _not_ have 'freedom of speech' on Stack Exchange, because that right only exists in terms of the United States government apparatus vs the United States citizen. Stack Exchange can set whatever rules they want for username content, 'free speech' be damned.

Answer (score 6):

> is it correct to add slogans or phrases with personal or political content in profile names

Correct? The question itself is incorrect.

Correct question can be "is it **legal** to add..." to which the answer is: Yes, it's legal by Stack Exchange terms of use, and there's no rule against it.

Comment: Ok, I see also from other answers that SE policy is not against political slogans in usernames. I can’t believe it but that’s the way it is.

Comment: @Gio as long as it's not offensive, yes SE allows it. Or more accurate to say, does not forbid it.

Comment: So it all comes down to what “offensive” means according to SE standards I suppose .

Comment: If you find something offensive you have the right to flag and report, and if the moderators will agree, they will reset the display name. Most people don't find names like "Support Ukraine" offensive, but each and their own.

Comment: Legal, but not (only) in the juridical sense?

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum Legal in the sense it's not forbidden by Stack Exchange rules, not legal in sense of actual law. Sadly I'm no lawyer so no idea about juridical.

Comment: This is really the only answer that can be given here. Yes, political, religious, and otherwise expressive and opinionated usernames are allowed, subject to the code of conduct. Whether something is "good" or "correct" is up to every person here individually; I frankly don't _want_ Stack Exchange (or any business/ platform for that matter) to try to be the arbiter of what is "good", that gets messy wayyy too quickly, and basically only ever has the effect of starting more arguments, rather than settling anything.

Comment: @zcoop98 true, the only way to really block any possible "wrong" or "bad" names is to simply not allow to choose/change display name. Have all users stay with the default user1912811 and be done with it. ("user" followed by the ID on the site where your first account has been created.)

Comment: Even name like "Bob" can be bad, wrong, and offensive to some people, for example someone who knows a person called Bob IRL and this Bob is bad and/or abusive. So should SE block the name "Bob"? Based on the logic of the OP the answer is Yes. And of course, this goes for any and all possible names, hence this is so utterly wrong.

Comment: @ShadowWizardSaysNoMoreWar why, I am sure a name like "user666" could be considered offensive on our religious sites! Fully agreed that policing usernames (unless they are against the CoC / ToS) is a can of worms we should better left unopen.